# Subquery with join and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a mysql table with 25 parent rows and 42 child rows. Child rows have the column `parent_id` which is the `id` of the parent row.  I'm only selecting parent rows with `category='general'` but i only want 5 child rows of those specific parent rows.

Here is the query i attempted below but doesn't work

```
 SELECT child.*,parent.title as ptitle FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE category='general' LIMIT 10) as parent
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `parent_id`=parent.id LIMIT 5) as child on child.`parent_id`=parent.id
  ORDER by parent.id ASC
```

I only want to fetch 5 child rows per parent row that have `child.parent_id=parent.id`.

Do i remove the second subquery WHERE clause because the ON clause takes care of this?

If not, how do i change the second subquery WHERE clause to accomplish this?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Once i added the second subquery WHERE clause, the query doesn't work.  I'm thinking that is where the error lies.

Comment: can you define what doesn't work is? it doesn't select anything? throws an error? what is it?

Comment: also please show some data so we can see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'll explain, the second subquery(child) should only fetch 5 rows `WHERE parent_id=parent.id`  .  But i've attempted this and it doesn't work.  If i removed the WHERE clause from the second subquery then it would just get the first 5 rows of `mytable`.

Comment: again when you say doesn't work. is that an error? if so what is the error message.. if its not an error is it just incorrect results?

Comment: I'm using PDO, how do i view an error message?  Anyway the screen is blank.  If i remove the second subquery WHERE clause then the query works but not the way i want it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php see the manual on how to catch an error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, parentid, category 
FROM
(   SELECT child.*, 
           IF(@a = child.parentid, @b:=@b+1, @b:=1) as counting_col, 
           @a := parent.id 
    FROM 
    (   SELECT * 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE category='general' 
        LIMIT 10
    ) as parent
    LEFT JOIN mytable child ON child.parentid=parent.id
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT @a :=0, @b:=1) t
    HAVING counting_col <=5
    ORDER by parent.id, child.id ASC
)t1;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0da059/1)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a third subquery?  i thought parent_id=parent.id would work.

Comment: from what I know you don't have access to that parent.id inside the join.

Comment: is all you want 5 rows returned?

Comment: yes, 5 child rows of a specific parent row.  So if 3 parent rows, then 15 child rows returned.  The only problem in my original post is the second subquery but you've now told me that i don't have access to the parent.id inside the join, so that is where the problem lies.

Comment: @user892134 can you please give me some data then? im flying blind here

Comment: @user892134 ok so now I understand your requirement... I cannot answer this without some data though... because to do something like this I need to test it myself.. it needs user defined variables..

Comment: Ok, i'm creating an SQLfiddle now.  Also performance wise will this be a slow query?

Comment: Here is the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0e84/3  The rows that should be returned are 5 child rows with `parentid='1'` . In my real data there are multiple parent rows with the category `general`.

Comment: Here is an updated query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d9e7/2  How do i LIMIT so only 5 child row are shown for a specific parent row?  Right now 7 child rows are shown for the row `parent1`